# Speed up IFFT calculation in Python

Tags: python, fft, enthought, ifft

I am working on a Python program (in Enthought Canopy) that will calculate the two point autocorrelation function for 2 and 3 dimensional images.

The core of the calculation is the following code:

```
fftx = fftn(newimpad)
del newimpad
ret_int = (fftx * np.conjugate(fftx))
del fftx
ret = ifftn(ret_int)
ret = fftshift(ret)
```

where `newimpad` is the padded image.

This works. However, the back transform (the `ifftn` step) is very slow - for the large images I have been working on in 2D it takes over 90 seconds.  Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Is your matrix conjugate symmetric? (Or more importantly, is it *nearly* symmetric?) If so you can add `"symmetric"` as an argument to `ifftn` to speed it up.

Comment: the original data is an 8-bit binary image of pore space in a solid matrix. it may or may not be isotropic. I do not know if the fft generated is a symmetric matrix.